# Automatic Configuration Script for proxy settings in Windows Phone 8

Tags: proxy, windows-phone-8

In order to use Wifi to access internet in my campus, I have to supply an automatic configuration script. Apparently when I connect to my institute's Wifi on my windows phone, I can supply the name of the proxy server and proxy port directly. But this doesn't work in my case. So is there any way (using a different browser maybe) by which I can specify and automatic configuration script to configure proxy settings for internet access in windows phone 8 ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean automatic configuration script similar to iOS's configuration profiles?

Comment: @Legoless Yes, I meant the same thing.

Comment: Then sorry, it is not possible according to my research.

Comment: Is your script in PAC format?